# "Optional" backreferences in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression with two groups that are OR'd and I'm wondering if it's possible to have a group be a back reference *only* if it matched? In all cases, I'm wanting to match **spam.eggs.com**

Example:

```
import re

monitorName = re.compile(r"HQ01 : HTTP Service - [Ss][Rr][Vv]\d+\.\w+\.com:(\w+\.\w+\.(?:net|com|org))|(\w+\.\w+\.(?:net|com|org))")

test = ["HQ01 : HTTP Service - spam.eggs.com",
    "HQ01 : HTTP Service - spam.eggs.com - DISABLED",
    "HQ01 : HTTP Service - srv04.example.com:spam.eggs.com",
    "HQ01 : HTTP Service - srv04.example.com:spam.eggs.com - DISABLED"]


for t in test:
    m = monitorName.search(t)
    print m.groups()
```

Produces:

```
(None, 'spam.eggs.com')
(None, 'spam.eggs.com')
('spam.eggs.com', None)
('spam.eggs.com', None)
```

It'd be nice if my groups would only return my one matched group and not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` operator has early precedence so it applies to *everything* before it (*from the beginning of your regex* in this case) OR everything after it. In your regex, if there is no "srv04.example.com", it isn't checking if the string contains "HTTP Service"!

Your two capturing groups are identical, so there's no point in having both. All you want is to have the `srv*:` part optional, right?

Try this one:

```
r"HQ01 : HTTP Service - (?:[Ss][Rr][Vv]\d+\.\w+\.com:)?(\w+\.\w+\.(?:net|com|org))"
```

Comment: Duh! Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
m = monitorName.search(t)
g = m.groups()
print g[0] or g[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `m.group(1) or m.group(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite the regular expression to be

```
monitorName = re.compile(r"HQ01 : HTTP Service - (?:(?i)SRV\d+\.\w+\.com:)?(\w+\.\w+\.(?:net|com|org))")
```

Produces

```
('spam.eggs.com',)
('spam.eggs.com',)
('spam.eggs.com',)
('spam.eggs.com',)
```

You can make group optional by tailing with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider this?

```
HQ01 : HTTP Service - (?:[Ss][Rr][Vv]\d+\.\w+\.com:)?(\w+\.\w+\.(?:net|com|org))
```